# Angular2 router's navigateByUrl() not calling ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have two Angular mini-apps on the same page. (Long story.) One is a navigation app, and one is the main app. I'm using the latest Angular router, based on [angular/vladivostok](https://github.com/angular/vladivostok).

It appears that the Angular router in one app (e.g., nav) does not respond to URL changes instantiated by the other app (e.g., the main app). So I've created a `RouterSynchronizer`<sup>1</sup> class that I provide to both apps. It listens to both routers' `NavigationEnd` events. When one router (let's call it the "source") has an event, it calls `navigateByUrl` on the other router (let's call it the "subscriber").

This works fine for the most part. However, it doesn't call `ngOnInit` on the components of the subscriber.

I've created [a Plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/apiwvsKPnL8WCoxYH062/) to demonstrate this, based on the live example from Angular's official [Routing & Navigation guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). Note that when you click the "Crisis Center" and "Heroes" links in the main app, `ngOnInit` is not called on the corresponding child components in the nav component. However, when you click those links in the nav component, `ngOnInit` *is* called on those child components, but *not* on the child components of the main app (which results in the lists of heroes/crisis centers being empty).

Any ideas? Thanks!

<sup>1</sup> `RouterSynchronizer` class:

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';

interface ISubscriber {
  id: string;
  router: Router;
}

export class RouterSynchronizer {
  private subscribers: ISubscriber[] = [];

  connect(id: string, router: Router): void {
    this.subscribers.push({ id, router });
    this.startPublishing(id, router);
  }

  private startPublishing(source: string, router: Router): void {
    router.events.subscribe(route => {
      if (route instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.subscribers.forEach(subscriber => {
          if (subscriber.id === source || subscriber.router.url === route.urlAfterRedirects) {
            // Prevent infinite loops.
            return;
          }

          subscriber.router.navigateByUrl(route.urlAfterRedirects);
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! Apparently, I needed to use a zone. See [the new Plunk](https://embed.plnkr.co/ugFk3oc4Zjk9NBDIfSF6/) for implementation.

The problem (I think!) is that my `RouterSynchronizer` class was instantiated and provided outside the Angular context. So it wasn't in an Angular zone when it pushed changes to the routers via `navigateByUrl`. Once I wrapped the `navigateByUrl` call in a zone *provided by the app*, it worked :)

Comment: If a method that emits an event is emitted in another Angular instance, then the zone of the current instance doesn't know about it. You need to use `zone.run(() => {})` as you did to make the code execute inside the zone of the current Angular2 application.

Answer (score -1):

You have to implement OnInit like so:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'nav-heroes',
    template: `<span *ngIf="hasRunOnInit">ngOnInit has run in NavCrisisCenterComponent</span>`,
})

export class NavCrisisCenterComponent implements OnInit {
    private hasRunOnInit: boolean;

    ngOnInit() {
    this.hasRunOnInit = true;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting adding `implements OnInit`? This doesn't actually have any runtime effect. It is just an indicator the TypeScript compiler of what methods it implements.

Comment: I ran your project and implemented OnInit it worked for me.

Comment: Implementing it will allow you to tap into the lifecycle hook, otherwise your OnInit is just another function. Ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#spy

Comment: Ron, could you describe what you mean by it "worked"? For example, it should say "ngOnInit has run in NavHeroesComponent" when clicking the **bottom** "Heroes" button.

Comment: Re: "otherwise your OnInit is just another function": [Angular's docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#interface-optional-) say the exact opposite: "Angular instead inspects our directive and component classes and calls the hook methods *if they are defined*. Angular will find and call methods like `ngOnInit()`, with or without the interfaces."

Comment: (For the sake of argument, I've updated the Plunker and included `implements OnInit`. It still doesn't work.)